# Error : segmentation fault

Tags: centos, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

My centos 7(1406) giving an error "segmentation fault " while trying to connect to the wireless using nmtui. My other wireless network connected successfully. It has been connected while installing the Operation system.
Any idea what happened or what the error means? When i try to add the connection through nmtui , the password is not saving.The system is an headless centos.

Answer (score 0):

I have manged to add the wireless network by using nmcli. I think it's something related to nmtui command. I found the help [from here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html)